# Pass keyboard input emulation to console application

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I have developed simple console menu program thats react on keyboard input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;


char* main_menu[] =
  {
    "1 - selection 1",
    "2 - selection 2",
    "3 - selection 3",
    "4 - selection 4",
    "q - quit",
    NULL
  };


char* menu2[] =
  {
    "a - selection a",
    "b - selection b",
    "c - selection c",
    NULL
  };


int getChoice( char* greet, char* choices[] )
{
  int chosen = 0;
  int selected;
  char** option;

  do
    {
      printf( "Choice: %s\n", greet );
      option = choices;
      while (*option)
    {
      printf( "%s\n", *option );
      option++;
    }
      do
    {
      selected = getchar();
      printf( "selected: %c\n", selected );
    } while ( selected=='\n' );
      option = choices;
      while (*option)
    {
      if ( selected == *option[0] )
        {
          chosen = 1;
          break;
        }
      option++;
    }
      if ( !chosen )
    {
      printf( "Incorrect choice, select again\n" );
    }
    } while( !chosen );
  return selected;
}

int getAmount( char* greet )
{
  int amount = 0;
  printf( "%s\n", greet );
  scanf("%d", &amount);
  return amount;
}




int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
int choice = 0;
  do
    {
      choice = getChoice( "Please select an action", main_menu );
      printf( "You have chosen: %c\n", choice );

    if ( choice == '1' )
    {
    printf( "choise 1");
    }
      else if ( choice == '2' )
    {
    printf( "choise 2");
    }
      else if ( choice == '3' )
    {

      int a = 0;
      a = getAmount( "type int value" );
      printf( "choise 3 entered %d",a);
    }
      else if ( choice == '4' )
    {
      int choice2 = 0;
      choice2 = getChoice( "Please select an action", menu2 );
      printf( "You have chosen: %c\n", choice2 );

      if ( choice2 == 'a' )
        {
          printf( "choise a");
        }
      else if ( choice2 == 'b' )
        {
          printf( "choise b");
        }
      else if ( choice2 == 'c' )
        {
          printf( "choise c");
        }
    }
    } while ( choice != 'q' );
  }
```

I would like to pass it sequences of keys in order to test it. I run command in bash and expect for key press 1:

echo 1 |./selector

But got noncontinuous loop of garbage characters :
Choice: Please select an action

```
1 - selection 1
2 - selection 2
3 - selection 3
4 - selection 4
q - quit
selected: �
Incorrect choice, select again
Choice: Please select an action
1 - selection 1
2 - selection 2
3 - selection 3
4 - selection 4
q - quit
selected: �
Incorrect choice, select again
Choice: Please select an action
```

What is wrong with my command or program?

Comment: You should be using C++ `string`'s and `vector`s, not raw char arrays. Also should probably use `cout`, not `printf`.

Comment: Why on earth are you using `char*` and `char**`?

Comment: Incidentally, you might want to look into using `expect` to create test drivers, which would be a more usual and more powerful way of automating input into an interactive program.

Comment: @TheDude Quite possibly is a homework assignment, which tend to avoid (for whatever dumb reason) the use of STL.

Comment: @Drise _"a homework assignmen"_ And does that make this question better or useful for anyone searching seriously about a c++ problem?

Comment: @TheDude Unlikely, and yet they get asked all the time.

Comment: @Drise Sure, and that's why I'm downvoting such and flag for closure.

Comment: @vico Something that may help us help you (and even help you find the problem yourself) is to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @TheDude However, in the [ontopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section of the help, #3 states `Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.` which I feel the OP has at least somewhat accomplished. He is however missing #1 `...  and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.`

Comment: @Drise It also says _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE]."_ I cannot spot any debugging efforts either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you do not check for end-of-file.

```
selected = getchar();
```

should be something like:

```
if ((selected = getchar())== EOF){exit(0);}
```